# Stuck on trying to resume paused (stopped) function - Pomodoro timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

First, JSFiddle does not properly display result of my code, so I'll use CodePen, if that's ok.
Well, I'm trying hard to make a Pomodoro timer, but I'm stuck on pause/resume session. I have to be able to stop executing the function on click(and it should display that particular moment on screen, for example 22:22), and on another click it should be resumed. I know that eval() is not desirable, but could someone please help me with completing my awful code (I know it's a mess, but I'm learning JS every day)? To be more precise, I've managed to pause/stop execution, but I need help with resuming it.
Here is the code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
   var toggle = true;
var a = document.getElementById("breakvalue");
  a.innerHTML = 7;
  var b = document.getElementById("sessionvalue");
  b.innerHTML = 25;
 $("#crcl").html("<h3>Session</h3>" + "</break>" + "<h1 id = numb>" + b.innerHTML + "</h1>");
  
 $("#breakplus").on("click", function(){
$("#breakvalue").html(eval(a.innerHTML)+1);
  });
  $("#breakminus").on("click", function(){
 if (a.innerHTML>=2){
$("#breakvalue").html(eval(a.innerHTML)-1);
      }
  });
  $("#sessionplus").on("click", function(){
$("#sessionvalue").html(eval(b.innerHTML)+1);
    $("#crcl").html("<h3>Session</h3>" + "</break>" + "<h1 id = numb>" + b.innerHTML + "</h1>");
  });
   $("#sessionminus").on("click", function(){
 if(b.innerHTML>=2){
$("#sessionvalue").html(eval(b.innerHTML)-1);
       $("#crcl").html("<h3>Session</h3>" + "</break>" + "<h1 id = numb>" + b.innerHTML + "</h1>");
       }
   });
  
 $("#crcl").on("click", function (){
   var capture = document.getElementById("crcl");
  
   var inner = capture.innerHTML;
  
  var head = document.getElementById("numb");
   
   var inn =  head.innerHTML;
 if(toggle&&isNaN(inn)){
   inter = setInterval(function(){
    console.log(inn);
    minutes = eval(inn.slice(0,2));
 
      seconds=eval(inn.slice(3));
    console.log(minutes);
    console.log(seconds);
   
    if(seconds>=0){
    $("#crcl").html("<h3>Session</h3>" + "</break>" + "<h1>" + minutes + ":" + seconds-- + "</h1>");}
        if (seconds<0){
         seconds=59;
         minutes = eval(minutes-1);
     $("#crcl").html("<h3>Session</h3>" + "</break>" + "<h1>" + minutes + ":" + seconds-- + "</h1>");}
     if(eval(minutes)<0){
       $("#crcl").html("<h1>BREAK!!!</h1>");
        clearInterval(inter);
       
      }
    toggle=false;
  }, 1000); 
     
   }
 if(toggle&&!isNaN(inn)){
  
  var minutes = eval(b.innerHTML-1);
      var seconds=59;
   
  inter = setInterval(function(){
      
    if(seconds>=0){
    $("#crcl").html("<h3>Session</h3>" + "</break>" + "<h1 id = numb>" + minutes + ":" + seconds-- + "</h1>");
    }
        if (seconds<0){
         seconds=59;
         minutes = eval(minutes-1);
     $("#crcl").html("<h3>Session</h3>" + "</break>" + "<h1 id = numb>" + minutes + ":" + seconds-- + "</h1>");}
     if(eval(minutes)<0){
       $("#crcl").html("<h1>BREAK!!!</h1>");
        
       clearInterval(inter);
      }
    toggle=false;
  }, 1000);
  }
   
if (!toggle) {
     clearInterval(inter);
     console.log(toggle);
     toggle=true;
     console.log(toggle);
    $("#crcl").remove();
  $(".center-block").html("<button type=button class= circle btn btn-primary id = crcl>" + inner + "</button>");
  }
  });
  
});
```

```css
h5{
  display:inline-block;
}
  p{
    font-size:30px;
}
.circle
{
width:500px;
height:500px;
border-radius:50%;
font-size:20px;
color:#fff;
line-height:500px;
text-align:center;
background:#000;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class = "container text-center">
  <div>
  <h1>Pomodoro Clock</h1>
  </div>
   
  <div class="container text-center" id = "length">
   
    <h5>BREAK LENGTH</h5>
     <h5>SESSION LENGTH</h5>
  </div>
  
    
  
       <div class="btn-group text-center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"id = "breakplus">+</button>
         <p id = "breakvalue"></p> 
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"id = "breakminus">-</button>
  
</div>
    
     <div class="btn-group text-center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id = "sessionplus">+</button>
         <p id = "sessionvalue"></p> 
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"id = "sessionminus">-</button>
  
</div>
   
    <div class="center-block"><button type="button" class=" circle btn btn-primary" id = "crcl"></button></div>
      
  </div>
</body>
```

This is the link to my [Codepen](http://codepen.io/pilgrim011/pen/vKojxX?editors=0011)

Ok, here is [JSFiddle, too.](https://jsfiddle.net/pilgrim011/6csxrh4j/12/)

Comment: This won't help the functionality of your code, but a neat thing that both CodePen and JSFiddle can do is to tidy up your indentations - try selecting all your code in HTML or JS views (`CTRL + A`), then use `SHIFT + TAB` to auto-indent. I've used it just to clean up other posts on SW before. Makes it a bit easier for everyone to read and assist.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. My mistakes were: forgetting h1 IDs on several places, putting minutes and seconds inside an if statement, and - biggest of all - putting stupid extra code inside the function:

```
 $("#crcl").remove();
$(".center-block").html("<button type=button class= circle btn btn-primary id = crcl>" + inner + "</button>");
```